# Excel AND function. Change True False to Yes and blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cells, excel-2016

I am searching for key words in a paragraph. If it contains these certain words, i want it to output yes in a different cell, but if it at all contains a word i do not want, it will output nothing (blank cell) on a different cell.

```
=AND(COUNT(SEARCH({"Red", "Yellow", "Pink"},BT3,))>0, COUNT(SEARCH({"Black"}, BT3)) = 0)
```

It works, but, I dont want the output to be True or False.

How can i fix it where if the word are in these it would result in yes. But if the word black is in the paragraph at all, it wouldnt output anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a better determining function would be COUNTIF with wildcards.

For almost all intents and purposes, FALSE is the same as zero and anything that is not false is TRUE.

```
=IF(AND(SUM(COUNTIF(BT3,{"*pink*","*red*","*yellow*"})), NOT(COUNTIF(BT3,"*black*"))), "yes", "")
```

Comment: And I wasn't aware that COUNT could be used here; I typically use ISNUMBER(SEARCH(..., ...)) to step over any potential error returns so thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `=IF()`,it's Easy:

```
=IF((COUNT(SEARCH({"Red","Yellow","Pink"},BT3))>0),1,"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but it would be along the lines of
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({"Red","Yellow","Pink"},BT3,))>0,"yes", IF (COUNT(SEARCH({"Black"},BT3))=0,"","oops")

If red yellow or pink is in the cell then yes will display.
If black is in the cell then it will display nothing.
If none of those words are in the cell it will display oops.

Comment: it seems that if the statement has red yellow and pink, its not outputting yes.